# git: Commit staged changes (without merge conflicts) during merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, git-merge-conflict, git-stage

We have a project (Microsoft Business Central) where we have to do a very big merge with thousands of merge conflicts. When we merge the two branches we get about half the changes as staged changes (where the merge was successful) and about half as changes with merge conflicts.

I would like to commit these staged changes before starting with the merge conflicts (because the merge conflicts have to be solved by different people). Unfortunately when I try to commit the staged changes I get the git error

```
"error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files."
```

Is there any possibility to commit only a part of an ongoing merge?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any possibility to commit only a part of an ongoing merge?

No.  I consider this a flaw in Git, and there are some *theoretical* methods for dealing with this, but there's nothing practical today.